# How to Properly Access Class Properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this class definition:

```
$.note = function() {}
$.note.prototype = {
  init: function(note) {
    this.note = note;
    this.ctrl = document.getElementById(note);
  },
  // I have these getter functions because I was getting errors using
  // myObject.note or myObject.ctrl
  getNote: function() {
    return this.note;
  },
  getCtrl: function() {
    return this.ctrl;
  }
}
```

I created a new object with this class like this:

```
var note = new $.note('C');
```

Which I can access in my console like this:
[image: Note]

But when I try and access note.getNote(), I get undefined as the response:
[image]

Am I going about accessing these properties incorrectly? I've tried using just note.note or note.ctrl, and I get the same thing...

Comment: I don'nt see you calling the init function

Comment: The code you are putting in your `init` prototype is typically code you’d want in your constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing's going to call that "init" function if you don't.

```
$.note = function(note) { this.init(note); }
```

Some frameworks provide an object system that uses constructor helper functions like that, but plain JavaScript doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.note = function(note) { this.note = note;}
```

or you should call init function:

```
var note = new $.note();
note.init('C');
```